# Storing a Spatial Index in Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, spatial-index

I would like to store an r-tree or quadtree index in a sqlite database using python.

Does anyone know if there is any code to do this?

A bit of background:

- The dataset cannot be moved to another format.
- the dataset in question is a shapefile
- Though there is spatial indexing for shapefiles, it's not meeting the needs
- I want to avoid using spatialite extension (it's messy to install on windows)

I can create a quadtree/rtree in-memory, but since the dataset is very large, the index takes a longtime to build. In addition, it consumes a large about of memory and effects other analysis down stream.  If I could store the index in sqlite it would help get past that issue I think.

Comment: You seem to deal with quite special case. Easiest way that I can imagine is to convert you data into GeoPackage with ogr2ogr and then utilize just the r-tree index that gets created automatically. By using the -sql option it is possible to skip the attributes which makes conversion faster.

Comment: I thought of this option, but like I stated, converting to GeoPackage is not an option.

Comment: What's the problem with converting data into GeoPackage if you just do  not use the geometry tables? You have .shp there and hopefully you can connect shapes with the row in index by the rowid.

Comment: I don't want to waste the time copying the datasets.

Comment: Have you measured how long it would take? Tell us what is acceptable and what is wrong with the native .shx index or the .qix index that GDAL can create.

Comment: The problem that I am encountering is in the number of edges overall. The shx and qix are not making my spatial queries quick. So I want to create another spatial index (SI) in an external file. Either in sqlite database or in a standalone file.  `libspatialindex` allows for the creation of an external SI as an r-tree index.  So I guess that is my best solution, though it's  not pure python (c-wrapper).